# Python AutoIndent on visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

In pycharm We can do Ctl+alt+l to reformat the code, How to achieve same functionality in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the [official docs](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/formatting/)

in settings json file we need to add

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

[image]